# Using CLI as a tool for nest project

Tags: command-line-interface, nestjs

I'm new in nodejs/nestjs, I want to build a new nest project and want to install nest cli as a command-line interface tool

I've tried on the following instruction from nest documentation the first step is to install nest/cli globally and when I tried the second steps which are using nest command it always end up showing an error that "nest" is not recognized as an internal or external command

step 1

```
$ npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```

step 2

```
$ nest new project-name
```

the error

```
'nest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 7):

The global npm binaries are probably not on your `PATH`, you have to add them:

Run the command `npm root -g` to find out where your global modules are installed, e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Then add `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` (without `node_modules`) to your `PATH`.

Comment: I added the global npm binary to the path following your response but it didn't work , but when I added specifically the nestjs ``C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli`` to the PATH and restarted vs code it worked  , not sure why the first one didnt work though .

Answer (score 5):

1. **Find the npm global path like this**

```
npm root -g
```

[image]

2. **Open EnvironMent variable**

[image]

3. **Select Environment Variables**

[image]

4. **Double Click on user defined variable path**

[image]

5. **Click on New Button and add the location in underlined row**

[image]

6. **Now Take new  command prompt and type `where nest` or `nest` Now it Works**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`npx @nestjs/cli new project-name`

This works for me for creating a project but didn't work to create a module for example.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the same problem by adding `nest` to system variables manually.

1. On the Windows desktop, right-click **My Computer**.
2. In the pop-up menu, click **Properties**.
3. In the **System Properties** window, click the **Advanced** tab, and then click **Environment Variables**.
4. In the **System Variables** window, highlight **Path**, and click **Edit**.
5. In the **Edit System Variables** window, insert the cursor at the end of the **Variable** value field.
6. If the last character is not a semi-colon (;), add one.
7. After the final semi-colon, type the full path to the file you want to find.
   For example: path C:\jdk
8. Click **OK** in each open window.

[Step by step guide took from here](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it is better to use npx instead of installing global npm packages, since you'll always use the latest version.

Just replace nest with npx @nestjs/cli for any command:

npx @nestjs/cli new project-name

Answer (score 0):

```
npm root -g
```

[image]

you can use core nodejs way

```
node "C:\Users\Hasif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\bin\nest.js" new project-name
```

this will be work like original command

```
nest new project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the global path

```
npm root -g
```

Then make sure nest cli is installed inside the node_modules there. In my case I forgot that I'm using NVM and switch to version where it doesn't have nest cli installed.

Answer (score -1):

We need to install nest. in document cli- nest forum i found that.

npm install -g @nestjs/cli

hope that useful.

Comment: The asker wrote that s/he did that in step 1 already...