# Command nest is not recognized

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, nestjs

I installed nestjs cli globally via npm command.

`npm i -g @nestjs/cli`

Installation was successful, but when I am trying to create new project via cli  using the command `nest new project-name` it says:
'nest' is not recognized as cmdlet name. So I used:

`npx @nestjs/cli new project-name`

this works but I continue having problems with commands nest in cli. I tried create a module using:
`nest g module module-name` and having the same problem "the term 'nest' is not recognized.
I tried to use npx @nestjs/cli instead nest just as for creating a new project but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CLI as a tool for nest project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249174/using-cli-as-a-tool-for-nest-project)

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Windows desktop, right-click My Computer.
2. In the pop-up menu, click Properties.
3. In the System Properties window, click the Advanced tab, and then click Environment Variables.
4. In the System Variables window, highlight Path, and click Edit.
5. Type npm root -g in your cmd.you get your root pakages path.
6. Add **C:\Users\Shahiq Shehzad\AppData\Roaming\npm** in your Environment Variable ignore last **node_modules**
7. Refresh Cmd
8. Thanks

Refresh cmd
thanks